# Swift - How to run a function x percent of the time?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that I want to run x percent of the time. example: when I tap a button, I want to run a function x percent of the time(the user enters 0.01, the function will run 1% of the time the button is tapped). Does anyone know how to do this in swift?

Comment: What do you mean "x% of the time" - Do you mean it runs every fraction of a second or it only executes for some fraction of a duration and then stops?  What is the function doing?  How long does it take to do what it is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a random function to determine whether a particular action should be undertaken:

```
func possiblyDoSomething(){
  if Int.random(1...100) == 1 {
    actuallyDoSomething() // will execute with a 0.01 chance
  }
}
```

`Int.random(1...100)` will choose a random number in the range from 1 to 100, so any one number has a chance of 0.01 to appear, so it doesn't matter what number you equate it to (I chose to check that it equals to  1 arbitrarily)

Comment: So I  would replace 100 with my numerator out of 100 right?

Comment: Yes, you can make it a variable

Comment: I may have misunderstood your previous comment. Int.random(1...100) will choose a random number in the range from 1 to 100, so any one number has a chance of 0.01 to be true. If you need a chance of 1/100, you'd choose the upper bound of that range to be the denominator (not the numerator)  @RyanD